# Testing local push notifications

Tags: ios, notifications, uilocalnotification, nsnotificationcenter

I recently had a iOS and Android game created.

They are using cocos2dx.

They have added local push notifications that work fine on Android but not on iOS.

The notifications are set for 4 hours, 1 day, 3 days and 7 days. However, i've tried playing the game, then turning my clock forward on my device to 5 days ahead - but no notifications appear.

Is this a correct way of testing? If not what is the best way of testing?

Comment: U want to push message from server to device & test ?

Comment: You could fire one immediately and if it doesn't populate then naturally the future ones won't either. Troubleshoot that way. Show some code

Answer (score 1):

The default `timeZone()` of a notification is set according to your location. So even if you manually change the device date and time, the notification will not fire up. For it to work properly you need to set the `timeZone()` to `systemTimeZone()`.

You can try this:

```
notification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.systemTimeZone()
```

Hope this helps. :)